# Match a token that spans more than one line

Tags: regex, scala

Consider the example string below:
"And is it possible to foster reconc-
iliation and peacebuilding?"

I would like to match the the token **reconc-iliation**.

Something like `"""(?m)\b[^\s]*\-$"""` matches **recon-** but `"""(?m)\b[^\s]*\-$^[^\s]*\b"""` does not match **reconc-iliation**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This would work**

```
\b(\S+-[\r\n]+\S+)\b
```

**UPDATE**

`^` --> matches start of line/ or start of string (depending on using `s` switch)

`$` --> matches end of line/ or end of string (depending on using `s` switch)

`\b` --> matches an word boundary

`\r` --> Carriage return

`\n` --> New line

Only windows uses both `\r` and `\n` as line separator.

Comment: Alright, that was simple... Thanks
Although, I wonder if \r\n works, why do they have $,^,?m... Do we lose any generality by using \r\n?

Comment: `^` and `$` don't match any characters—they match an empty string at the beginning/end of the string.  *?m* is for altering the default behavior of `^` and `$` from matching at the beginning/end of the string to matching at the beginning/end of the line.  They still match an empty string, though, so they're not the same as `[\r\n]`.